# How to get the installed Memory Type

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory

Windows 7 could be better at this, it tells everything about the computer CPU but only the Memory amount

[image]

Microsoft **should add information** about DDR type, speed and maybe CL as well.

While this never happens, **What's the best and easy way to check the installed memory** so we can buy and upgrade it?

I was thinking a **simple software** so I don't need to install the full SiSoft Sandra for example, just looking for something small, only for the memory part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [cpu-z](http://download.cnet.com/CPU-Z/3000-2086_4-10050423.html) it will give you exactle the info you need.

Answer (score 1):

[Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) can help you. [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) is also fine.